# How to add a column to every dataframe in the workspace based on its name?

Tags: r, dataframe

### Background

First I'll initialize some dummy dataframes (NOTE: in the real example there will be >40 dataframes):

```
colOne <- c(1,2,3)
colTwo <- c(6,5,4)
df_2004 <- data.frame(colOne,colTwo)
df_2005 <- data.frame(colTwo,colOne)
```

### Problem

Now what I want to do is loop through every data frame in the workspace and add a column called `year` to them, filled with `2004` if the suffix is `_2004` and `2005` if the suffix is `_2005`.

I can start by getting a list of all of the data frames in the workspace.

```
dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(),function(t) is.data.frame(get(t)))]
dfs
```

```
[1] "df_2004" "df_2005"
```

But that's as far as I've managed to get.

### Attempted Solution

This is what I tried:

```
for (d in dfs) {
  d <- lapply(d, function(x){
    t <- get(x)
    if (grepl('2004',x)) {
      t$year <- 2004
    } else {
      t$year <- 2005
    }
    t
  })
}
```

This does not throw an error, but it doesn't do anything either other than set `d` to `"2005"`.

If I add a line `print(t)` right before the line returning `t`, I get this output in the console:

```
  colOne colTwo year
1      1      6 2004
2      2      5 2004
3      3      4 2004
  colTwo colOne year
1      6      1 2005
2      5      2 2005
3      4      3 2005
```

suggesting that the code gets through that part fine, because that's exactly what I want `df_2004` and `df_2005` to look like respectively. But `df_2004` and `df_2005` are not actually changed, which is what I want.

Comment: Are your data frames actually in a list? What's the name of the list? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say two list as `d_2018` and `d_2019`. Using `lapply`,

```
d_2018 <- lapply(d_2018, function(x){
  x$year <- 2018
  x
})

d_2019 <- lapply(d_2010, function(x){
  x$year <- 2019
  x
})
```

will helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `purrr` to add new column from the dataframe name.

```
library(purrr)

year_data <- list(data_2018, data_2019)

res <- map(year_data, function(x) 
        imap(x, function(data, name) {
        transform(data, year = sub('.*?_', '', name))
        }))
```